# How to select unique row records in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with columns number, name, address & contact, i want to display unique in a row like say

```
number , name, address, contact
1 , joy, Elgin , Obere Str. 57
2 , saf, Berlin ,Obere Str. 57
3 , andy, Berlin, Avda. de la Constitución 2222
3 , rin, Berlin ,Mataderos 2312
```

Display like this

```
number , name, address, contact
1 , joy, Elgin , Obere Str. 57
2 , saf, Berlin ,Obere Str. 57
3 , andy, Berlin, Avda. de la Constitución 2222
```

How ?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 4):

Most databases support the ANSI-standard `row_number()` function.  You can do this as:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by number order by number) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  this chooses an arbitrary row from matching numbers, which seems entirely consistent with the phrasing of the question.

Comment: Why would this necessarily choose "rin" over "andy"? I don't think there's enough information in the question to truly give an answer, and `order by number` is potentially unintentionally misleading?

Comment: @ic. . . . The question is pretty clear: "i want to display unique in a row like say . . .".  The example data is part of the "like".  I see no specification that the desired row is anything other than arbitrary.

Comment: Oh, definitely agreed, I just worry about the next person to come along and find this question from a search engine. But maybe I'm thinking too hard :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff should be a simple solution

Comment: I am using this query also but display all records select number , name, address, contact
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by number order by number) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;

Comment: @bharat . . . This query should be returning only one row per `number`.  If it is showing all numbers, then there are no duplicates.

Comment: This is a right query select number , name, address, contact
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by number order by number) as seqnum
      from table t where status='P'
     ) t
where seqnum = 1

Comment: This query select number , name, address, contact from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by number order by number) as seqnum from table t ) t where seqnum = 1 returns no of rows but there are no duplicates number i.e. number , name, address, contact
1 , joy, Elgin , Obere Str. 57
2 , saf, Berlin ,Obere Str. 57
3 , andy, Berlin, Avda. de la Constitución 2222

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(number),name,address, contact from tableName where status='p' group by number
```

Comment: I used this query also but all records are display

Comment: select min(number),name,address ,contact from tableName where status='p' group by number

Comment: I used this one also but same

Comment: I got right answer select number , name, address, contact from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by number order by number) as seqnum from table t where status='P' ) t where seqnum = 1

Comment: While this code may solve the OP's problem, a few words of explanation would be even more helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

select distinct number , name, address, contact
order by id;